# Display the "Comment on Delete" dialog on normal deletion too

Tags: feature-request, comments, vote-to-delete, automatic-comments

In the review queues, when we vote to delete a post, we get a nice dialog with possible comments asking why we're deleting this post.

Is it possible to make this dialog appear when casting normal delete votes as well?

It can be helpful to add automatic comments even without going through the review queue (i.e. if I found the question by browsing or by flags if I am a moderator).